# How to check how many times a function has been called in a test?

Tags: go, testing

I'm working on a web server with an API which calls a function. This function does a heavy job and caches the result. I've designed it in a way that if there is no cache and multiple users call this API with the same parameters at the same time, the server call that function only once for the first request and all other requests wait for finishing the job and return response from the cache.

I've written a test for it in this way:

```golang
func TestConcurentRequests(t *testing.T) {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            // do the request
            wg.Done()
        }
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

I can check that my code works correctly by printing a value inside that heavy function and check the console to see if it appears only once, but I'm searching for a way to fail the test if this function has been called more times. Something like this:

```golang
if n := NumberOfCalls(MyHeavyFunction); n > 1 {
    t.Fatalf("Expected heavy function to run only once but called %d times", n)
}
```

Comment: Normally, you probably should _not_ test how many times a function is called. You should check, instead, that it produces the output you expect. In theory, it should be possible to refactor the code, so that the function is called more times, or fewer (possibly 0 times). If that happens, and the code still behaves correctly, the test should pass.  In other words: Most tests that check for number of function executions are actually testing the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest breaking your heavy function into Cache part and actual processing part. Here Cache part will be facade to the concurrent clients. The **system under test** here actually is the cache layer that decides whether to forward the request, hold or return from cache. So in order to test that you need to mock the actual function that does processing and the mock should record how many requests it served.

Here is the demonstration with certain assumptions:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func CreateCachedProcessor(processor Processing) func(string) string {
    //cache here
    return func(req string) string {
        //Assume you have some logic to call the actual processor based on your conditions
        return processor.ProcessRequest(req)
    }
}

type Processing interface {
    ProcessRequest(string) string
}

type HeavyProcessing struct{}

func (p *HeavyProcessing) ProcessRequest(request string) string {
    return "response"
}

type HeavyProcessingRecorder struct {
    Count int
}

func (p *HeavyProcessingRecorder) ProcessRequest(request string) string {
    p.Count += 1
    return "response recorded"
}

func main() {

    //normal
    hp := &HeavyProcessing{}
    c := CreateCachedProcessor(hp)
    fmt.Println(c("req1"))

    //Test with recorder
    hpr := &HeavyProcessingRecorder{}
    cr := CreateCachedProcessor(hpr)
    cr("req1")
    cr("req1")
    cr("req1")
    fmt.Println("No. of times Called ", hpr.Count)

}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your detailed response. In the mean time, I've found  an easier solution. I assign my heavy function to a variable which will be called by my API handler. Then in the test case, I change the value of that variable to a higher order function which will call the original function and increment an outer scope integer value after each call. Finally, I should check the value of that int variable.

Comment: Whatever works for you is fine. Also that is what `hpr` variable is in my case. But I don't want to put Count variable over there because I consider that as system under test which is CachedProcessor (production functionality). The recorder should be outside of the system under test.